# margin between 2 span

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<div class='relative'>
    <span>MyText</span><br>
    <span class="btnFavorit btnViolet" idp="005626">
            <span class="l">&nbsp;</span><span class="c"> <img class="imageOff" src="./charte/base/mesCourses/pictoFavorit.png"><img class="imageOn" src="./charte/base/mesCourses/pictoFavoritOn.png">BUTTON</span><span class="r">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to put a margin bottom on the first span to have a space between the text and my button (made by span) . How I can do it (For me I think I will use other 
 but I don't know if I can use CSS for this)

Comment: so you can add another `<br>`

Comment: Yes but if I would like to have exactly 8px of margin I can't with <br>

Comment: That was joke, surely it's always better to use css ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
.relative span { display: inline-block; }
.relative span:first-child { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have more space between these spans. You can set css rule to do it:

```
br { 
line-height:10px;
}
```

or

```
br { 
margin: 15px 0;
display: block;
}
```

That would change all brs in your page. Add class to br in order to have css specific in only one place:

```
<span>MyText</span><br class="gap">
```

and then you use css:

```
br.gap { 
margin: 15px 0;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add class to first span, give it a display property as `inline-block` or `block` and put margin :-)

```
.textSpan{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px; /*increase if you want*/
}
```

**Why only margin does not work for `span`?**
Span element is `inline` unlike block elements like `p, div` hence you need to specifically give it a custom display property like `block` or `inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/wk483kzL/

Answer (score 0):

The span tag should be used for inline elements ONLY. Best solution would be to change MyText span to a div, as this is your desired effect.

```
<div>MyText</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this..

```
<style>
.relative span:first-of-type { display:inline-block;margin-bottom:10px; }
</style>
```